# JAXRS / RestEasy Limit rate of requests

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy, jboss6.x

I have a Restful API that is used for uploading some files via POST to a server from remote nodes

If I take the server down the uploads are queued remotely so that when the server comes back online there may be a large amount of requests coming in that can bring down the server

The application is hosted across a cluster of JBoss servers with an Apache front end

So my question is: Are there any built-in/efficient solutions for limiting the number of concurrent requests? Either at the Apache / JBoss / RestEasy - Application level

At the moment, the API called has to return a 200 (Success) otherwise the upload stays in the remote queue and will retry after a fixed time period

I am thinking of just storing the current number of requests in the database and setting a threshold, if the theshold is exceeded then reject the request so that the remote node trys again after an amount of time, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

If you access to the REST application through apache with mod_proxy perhaps you can try to limit the max number of concurrent connections to the backend, something like:

```
ProxyPass /application/rest http://localhost:8080/application/rest max=10
ProxyPass /application http://localhost:8080/application
```

This way you should limit the connections to /application/rest to a max number of 10. Taken from apache doc http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Do note, that this works only if your Apache has been compiled with MPM mode on. If the Apache compiled to prefork mode, it spawns a new process for every request and the "max" attribute affects only each process, thus having no real effect.

Comment: interesting...I am using mod_proxy, wasn't aware of this option, il give it a go and report back